# Call to javascript function do not pass class variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I am not so good with javascript and I do hope you're tougher than me. Here is my problem: I use MicrosoftAjax.cs framework and I use classes like this one :

```
MyClass =
{
teststring:null,
$constructor: function(test){
teststring = "test";
},
GetInformationFromName : function(inputname, BeginningSeparator, EndSeparator) {
    alert(BeginningSeparator);
    alert(EndSeparator);
},
GetId: function(inputname) {
            return MyClass.GetInformationFromName(inputname,MyClass.teststring, "???");
        }
}
```

It is a pretty straightforward function where i just want to extract information from a name given in GetId().

My problem is that In GetPerId I can see (in the debugger of visual studio) the value of  MyClass.teststring. But when I debug into the call of the function and I arrive in GetInformationFromName, the value passed in parameter is null, whereas a "normal" value does not cause any trouble.

concrete example of what happens (of what i can see) :
-> GetId("toto")
-> MyClass.GetInformationFromName("toto","&", "???");
-> GetInformationFromName (toto",null, "???")

Would you have any hint about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `teststring` properly in your constructor.  Notice how, everywhere else, when calling class variables and methods you need to use `MyClass.methodname` or `MyClass.variablename`?  In your constructor, you just set `teststring="test"` when you should be setting `MyClass.teststring="test"` to override the default value of `null`.

I don't see a `GetPerId` method in your code snippet, so I can't explain why VS is displaying the correct value there, but I can tell you that your constructor is setting a *local* variable of `teststring` and you're passing a *global* variable when you call `GetInformationFromName` in `GetID`.

Also, I can't see if and when you call `$constructor` anyway ... so I'm not 100% sure you're even setting the local `teststring` variable.

Answer (score 0):

thkx for anyone who share a thought on this one, i found my mistake. I should have use the constructor like this:

```
$constructor: function(test){
MyClass.teststring = "test";
}
```

sorry for the bother, hope it helps someone one day...